# Query in light switch returns only one line?

Tags: sql, view, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a query which is called by two Parameters Invoice number & Company name. the query returns always one line in Light switch. Usually it should returns more than one line (Depends on what invoice number I am looking for). I donot know why its always returning one line ? The query is connected to a view in SQL server. I tried to test the query in SQL serve and I always get the correct lines. but when i call the same query with the same Parameters in light switch it gives me only one line as a result. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is caused when the primary key(s) for the table have duplicate values in the data returned. Look at the entity (in the LightSwitch Entity designer in the server project) LightSwitch created when you attached the view and see what it thinks the primary key(s) are.

In order to solve this problem:
You just have to create or add anew Primary Key to the current keys in your view.

Best Regards,
Mohamed